# Meteor fill a form with data from database if there is one, if not show the form

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, radio-button, autofill

i'm learning how to work with MeteorJS. I'm trying to prefill a form with the return from the database, and all the text inputs have no problem, but how could i checked a radio?? what i'm getting from the database is a very long form, with at least 150 fields. so i'll have to deal with this a lot, but i don't know how. obviously i'm already retrieving the correct document, all the other fields are fine, the value from the radios are fine, but how do i add the checked attribute to them with handlebars o any other way.

```
Template.myTemp.helpers({
   full : function () {
      var id = Session.get('currentId');
      if (id) {
         return People.findOne({_id: id});
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   }
});
```

ok, so here the return true is just to show the form with no prefill values if the Session has not been define. next in a short version of my template

```
<template name="myTemp">
  {{#with full}}
  <div class="input-field">
        <label for="name" class="active">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value= "{{name}}">
  </div>
  <p>
        <input id="fem" name="sex" type="radio" value="FEM" class="with-gap">
        <label for="fem">Female</label>
        <input id="male" name="sex" type="radio" value="MALE" class="with-gap">
        <label for="male">Male</label>
  </p>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

so here is the trick, when i use this form to insert it works great, but when trying to prefill it, its a nightmare. how could i check this radio buttons if the value i'm getting in return is the value from the form that is stored in the database under the name of sex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the documents of your `People` collection look similar to the following objects:

```
{ "_id" : "adCsEGoHFbpJbFjtP", "name" : "John Doe", "sex" : "male" }
{ "_id" : "TYLDYicCzpHSD5Sk5", "name" : "Jane Doe", "sex" : "female" }
```

If this is the case, you could define a helper in your `myTemp` template which returns the String `checked` if the document's attribute `type` matches the function's argument:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.myTemp.helpers({
        full: function () {
            var id = Session.get('currentId');
            if (id) return People.findOne({_id: id});
            else return true;
        },
        isChecked: function (type) {
            return (this && this.sex === type) ? 'checked' : null;
        }
    });
}

People = new Mongo.Collection("people");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        People.insert({
            "name": "John Doe",
            "sex": "male"
        });
        People.insert({
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "sex": "female"
        });
    });
}
```

---

```
<template name="myTemp">
    {{#with full}}
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="name" class="active">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="{{name}}">
        </div>
        <p>
            <input id="fem" name="sex" type="radio" value="FEM" class="with-gap" {{isChecked 'female'}}>
            <label for="fem">Female</label>
            <input id="male" name="sex" type="radio" value="MALE" class="with-gap" {{isChecked 'male'}}>
            <label for="male">Male</label>
        </p>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Here is a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/hYSrF9EJrrFgFdz6u/Meteor-Fill-Form-Radio).

Comment: i've tried your code as you supply it and it works great. but could you help me a bit, i do not understand how is the function (type) working. where does the argument type is coming from. i couldn't make it work with my code, even by copy a paste of your code. so i think if i can get to understand your code i may be able to make things work

Comment: The argument `type` can be passed per Meteor template helpers like `{{isChecked 'female'}}` or `{{isChecked 'male'}}`.